# multiple methods annotated by ModelAttribute. How to set method's invocation order

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller

I have so @Controller:

```
  @Controller
    public class CandidateMenuController{
        @ModelAttribute(value = "vacancies")
        public Set<Vacancy> loadVacancies() {
            return vacancyService.getAll();
        }


        @ModelAttribute(value = "vacanciesForCandidate")
        public Set<Vacancy> vacanciesForCandidate(@RequestParam(required = false)                List<Integer> vacanciesSelected,
                                                  @ModelAttribute("vacancies")Set<Vacancy> allVacancies ) {
            .....
        }
}
```

Sometimes it works good, but sometimes I saw exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [java.util.Set]: Specified class is an interface
```

Obviously that it depends for order of @ModelAttrributes methods invocation.

I understand that I can manually invoke necessary method inside @ModelAttribute method manually but
How can  I manage of  @ModelAttribute methods invocation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767120/org-springframework-beans-beaninstantiationexception-could-not-instantiate-bean... Different user(?), same code, basically same question.

Comment: there are I ask the cause of exeception. here I understand cause, but look for solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot, basically the `@ModelAttribute` annotation on a method cannot be combined with a `@ModelAttribute` annotation on an argument. And I would also strongly advice against it. It makes your controller quite brittle to changes and prone to errors (imho that is).

Why not simply write a single method return void, including the `Model` as an argument and be done?

```
@ModelAttribute
public void referenceData(@RequestParam(required=false) List<Integer> vacanciesSelected, Model model) {
    Set<Vacancy> vacancies= vacancyService.getAll();
    model.addAttribute("vacancies", vacancies);
    if (vacanciesSelected != null && !vacanciesSelected.isEmpty() ) {
        Set<Vacancy> vacanciesForCandidate = // Do something with the set
        model.addAttribute("vacanciesForCandidate", vacanciesForCandidate);
    }
}
```

Robust solution which doesn't rely on method ordering.

Comment: I wrote about this solution in my topic.  I think spring mvc creaters must forbid of using annotattion ModelAttribute in method params, that annotate  ModelAttribute

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: In my topic I wrote about this solving

Comment: Why should it lead to a compilation error. It is perfectly valid javacode and sort of works but you shouldn't do it. There is nothing the compiler can do about that, the only thing that could be done is that there would be an error when parsing the @ModelAttribute methods when starting your application.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is taken as an [improvement](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6299) and the latest release of spring framework supports the inter-dependency of @ModelAttribute annotating methods.

For more information please refer this [commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/56a82c1cbe8276408f9fff06cfb1ac9da7961a80)